# Moving the rows in my grid

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble trying to move the rows to the left. The grid is from my input.txt file that I created.I created the method RL which is supposed to move the rows to the left.

This is what I have so far

```
    while(true){
        showBoard();
        Scanner kbScan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Input number from 1 to 5: ");
        int  i = kbScan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input move command: ");
        String moveName = kbScan.next();
        //If/ else statements to dictate which method to call
        if(moveName.equals("rl")){

            RL(i-1, board);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("rr")){

            RR(i+1);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("ru")){

            RU(i-1);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("rd")){

            RD(i-1);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("+r")){

            plusRow(i-1);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("-r")){

            minusRow(i-1);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("+c")){

            plusColumn(i-1);
        }
        else if(moveName.equals("-c")){

            minusColumn(i-1);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Please follow instructions");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    // In case user inputs # greater than 5


}
public static void showBoard(){
    for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col<board.length;col++){
            System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}

public static void RL(int userPosition, int[][] board){
    for(int row = 0; row< board.length ;row++){
        for(int col = 0; col<board.length;col++){
            int value = board[row][col];

        }
    }

}
```

This is the output I'm getting :

```
    Input number from 1 to 5: 
    1
    Input move command: 
    rl

    1  -2  1  0  0   
    -1  0  4  2  0   
    0  -4  1  -1  0   
    0  1  -1  -1  -2   
    0  -3  1  -1  0
```

This is the output I want to get:

```
    -2  1  0  0 1  
    -1  0  4  2  0   
    0  -4  1  -1  0   
    0  1  -1  -1  -2   
    0  -3  1  -1  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the RL method doesn't do anything.  It just creates temporary variables name temp.

**EDIT**: This will rotate an array to the left one, wrapping around the first value.  Now all you need to do is apply it to the 2D array, which is trivial (match it to the input).

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

System.out.println("Before:");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println():


if (arr.length > 0) {
    int first = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }

    arr[arr.length-1] = first;
}

System.out.println("After:");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: I know the method doesn't do anything right now. I tried the System.out.print(board[rows-1][col]); , But right now I'm confused. Am I far off .

Comment: So, for each row in the array you want to move the values to the left, wrapping around if need be?

Comment: I'm trying to move the row the user selects to the left.